# Making [tag:simulator] a synonym for [tag:simulation]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I've not the required rep to use the usual tag synonym proposal procedure. I think [simulator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulator) should be made a synonym for [simulation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation). There's already such a pending proposal for that. Probably a mod should step-in and act accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (currently) 35 [simulator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulator) questions, and 355 [simulation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation) questions. While there *could* be a distinction between the two tags, in practice there isn't.

*Edit*: With a community vote of 3 in favor, 1 against, the tags will be merged.